# C - passing an array by reference - only first element set

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have a function which should modify an array (of floats) in the original parent function. I am using the following code:

```
void sortFunction(Word**words, int wordCount){ //to sure if two * are correct (pointer to an array..?)
int i = 0;
for(i=0;i<wordCount-1;i++){
  Word first = *words[i]; //values fine
  Word second = *words[i+1]; //weird values, causes segfault
    if(first.data[0] > second.data[0]){
      //do stuff
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  Word* words = NULL;
  int wordsCount = ...
  //filling the array in a loop and using realloc for memory allocation
  //Here, the array is filled correctly (verified)
  sortFunction(&words, wordsCount);
}
```

Where `Word` is a typedef struct and `Word.data` is the (dynamic) float array. When checking in the parent function, the array is allocated and the values set correctly.

I have tried with about 10 elements in the array, but always only the first ([0]) element is fine in the `sortFunction()`, second and all others are messed up. I also have an `int` propery in the struct, and when I try to print it for the second element, I get something over 1 billion.

I assume I am not passing the array correctly - I use the following code (just a sample) to pass regular variables, so I tried to modify it for an array, but apparently, not correctly. What is the right way to do this for an array?

```
void foo(int*var){
  *var=8;
}

int main(){
  int var = 5;
  changeVar(&var);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Read e.g. [this operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and the problem should be obvious.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sadly not :/ I guess (as I thought before), that it has something to do with the `Word**words` part?

Comment: No, not that part, but the `*words[i]` part. The compiler treats it as `*(words[i])` which is wrong.

Comment: You don't need to pass in `words` as pointer to pointer (`**`) if you only change the content, not the array itself

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So it should be something like (*words)[i]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*words[i]` is parsed as `*(words[i])`, which isn't what you want.

You need to dereference the `words` pointer *before* applying the subscript, so you need to explicitly group the `*` operator with `words` using parentheses:

```
Word first = (*words)[i];
Word second = (*words)[i + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need to pass `**`, just one is enough, because you will be passing the address of your array anyway:

```
void sortFunction(Word* words, int wordCount)
```

and call it as:

```
sortFunction(words, wordsCount);
```

Second, the Undefined behavior originates in the following statement:

> `Word first = *words[i];   Word second = *words[i+1];`

It should have been `(*words)[i]` but still, you are copying structs, so your *dynamic* `data` array is not copied correctly. avoid this useless copy, and use this instead, AFTER changing the protoype of sortFunction:

```
Word* first = &words[i];
Word* second = &words[i+1];
if(first->data[0] > second->data[0])
```

p.s: This does not guarantee that the rest of your code is correct, just comments of the parts you showed of the code.